# .length trava todo o código

Tags: jquery, login, método

Preciso saber se o usuário esta logado através do Javascript (jQuery) para rodar alguns comandos (puramente estéticos). A alternativa mais rápida que encontrei foi criando um `hidden input` que só é colocado na página caso o usuário esteja logado (verificado através do PHP) e verificar pelo jQuery se aquele `input` existe. Porém quando coloco o código abaixo dentro de um `$(document).ready()` junto com outras funções, nenhuma delas funciona mais, todo meu jQuery vai pro saco. Segue o código:

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
   .
   .
   .
   if ($("#estoulogado").length)
   {
      $("#email").prop('disabled', true);
      if ($("#estoulogado").attr('faoulo') == "fabrica")
      {
        $("#lojas").prop('disabled', true);
        $("#selectdepartamentos").prop('disabled', true);
        $("#nome").prop('disabled', true);
      };
      else if ($("#estoulogado").attr('faoulo') == "loja")
      {
        $("#fabrica").prop('disabled', true);
        $("#selectlojas").prop('disabled', true);
      };
   };
   .
   .
   .
});
```

Abrindo o console (como sugerido pelo Renan) encontrei um erro de sintaxe nessa linha:

`$("#email").prop('disabled', true);`

O erro é o seguinte: `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token (`

Não importa o que eu coloque dentro do `if`, todo o meu código trava, não funciona. Por que isto ocorre? Também aceito uma ideia melhor que essa pra verificar se o usuário está logado.

Comment: Está a faltar um `)` no fim do código... deve ser `});`. Será esse o seu problema?

Comment: provável que seja um erro de sintaxe. abra o console e verifique

Comment: Ah, esqueci de colocar o `)` no código postado aqui, vou editar, mas está certo no código real.

Comment: Se a consola indicar algum erro, adicione essa informação na pergunta. Qualquer erro em Javascript faz com que todos os scripts parem após o erro na maioria dos navegadores.

Comment: Meu código todo roda normal, mas a hora que fui adicionar essa parte, TUDO parou de funcionar.

Comment: @Rafael não custa mais do que cinco segundos do seu tempo apertar F12 e ver se há um erro na consola. Se não houver erro na consola, indique isso na pergunta também, pois isso é importante para determinar a causa do problema.

Comment: Desculpa Renan, acho que você achou que eu não queria olhar o console. Quando você mandou o comentário eu já estava olhando o console e editando a pergunta. Editei a pergunta e coloquei o código completo que está dentro do if. Obrigado Renan

Comment: @Rafael sem problemas. É um erro de sintaxe, ok? Algum par de parênteses não está fechado corretamente em seu codigo, e não é na instrução onde o erro é mostrado.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Encontrei o erro. Estou postando como resposta pois fiz a pergunta como convidado e ao completar o meu registro não consigo mais comentar na pergunta pois ela não consta mais como minha.

Antes queria agradecer o Renan por ter me ajudado, se não fosse ele acho que não teria encontrado o erro, pois ainda estaria achando que o problema era o `.length`. Mas como sou novo usuário e a pergunta não mais me pertence, não posso lhe dar reputação.

Então vamos ao erro.

O problema estava no ponto-e-vírgula após as chaves do `if` dentro do `if`.
Como existe um `else` depois dele, não poderia haver um ponto-e-vírgula ali.

Obrigado pela ajuda gente.

Answer (score 3):

O erro `Unexpected token (` significa que há um par de parênteses mal fechado no código. Duas considerações:

- Foi indicado inicialmente na pergunta que faltava um parêntese no código. Você corrigiu, mas se ainda obtém o mesmo erro é porque há mais pares de parênteses mal fechados. Isso está no código que você não mostrou;
- O erro não ocorre na instrução que o console lhe indica. `$("#email").prop('disabled', true);` é sintaticamente correto.

Algumas sugestões:

- Aproveite melhor sua IDE. A maioria marca erros de sintaxe visualmente para facilitar sua correção;
- Das expressões mais aninhadas para as mais externas, apague pares de parênteses com tudo que houver dentro deles. No final acaba sobrando o que não foi fechado.

Boa sorte!

Answer (score 1):

Está faltando um **)** no final do código

Faça deste modo

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
   .
   .
   .
   if ( $("#estoulogado").length )
   {
   .
   .
   .
   }
   .
   .
   .
});
```

Comment: Só estava errado no código postado, no código real está certo, já editei, obrigado.